# i want to attach a feature that when these app install in any mobile then go to app permissions like that image

Tags: android

I am just making an app which will capture image by camera and show in another activity and then upload on firebase that work fine .But I want to attach a feature that  *when this app is installed in any mobile then go to app permissions like below image*

this is my code first activity code

```
    camera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.takePic);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            // Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,PostActivity.class);
            // startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK)


    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Log.e("Image : ", uri.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PictureActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("imgUrl", uri.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

this is second activity code

```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        // path = (Uri) bundle.get("imgUrl");

        Log.e("ashish", bundle.getString("imgUrl") + "");
        path = Uri.parse(bundle.getString("imgUrl"));


    }

    ImageView selfiiii = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mySelfie);
    selfiiii.setImageURI(path);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A work around for this is by opening the app setting. Not the direct permission panel.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

or you could do a runtime permission request. To open dialog

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1);
```

and to get result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                   String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
   switch (requestCode) {
     case 1: {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           //Permitted! do Something
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }
  }
}
```